# Корейский random

Tags: java

В чем разница между:

```
(int) (java.lang.Math.random()*$int)
```

и

```
java.util.Random rand=new java.util.Random();
rand.nextInt($int);
```

где $int - переменная типа int?

**Заранее спасибо!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй вариант предпочтительнее.
Math.random() внутри использует Random.nextDouble().

Если интересуют подробности работы, то вот откопал описание с Sun-овского форума:

> Random.nextDouble() uses Random.next()
> twice to generate a double that has
> approximately uniformly distributed
> bits in its mantissa, so it is
> uniformly distributed in the range 0
> to 1-(2^-53).
>
> Random.nextInt(n) uses Random.next()
> less than twice on average- it uses it
> once, and if the value obtained is
> above the highest multiple of n below
> MAX_INT it tries again, otherwise is
> returns the value modulo n (this
> prevents the values above the highest
> multiple of n below MAX_INT skewing
> the distribution), so returning a
> value which is uniformly distributed
> in the range 0 to n-1.
>
> Prior to scaling by 6, the output of
> Math.random() is one of 2^53 possible
> values drawn from a uniform
> distribution.
>
> Scaling by 6 doesn't alter the number
> of possible values, and casting to an
> int then forces these values into one
> of six 'buckets' (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
> each bucket corresponding to ranges
> encompassing either 1501199875790165
> or 1501199875790166 of the possible
> values (as 6 is not a disvisor of
> 2^53). This means that for a
> sufficient number of dice rolls (or a
> die with a sufficiently large number
> of sides), the die will show itself to
> be biased towards the larger buckets.
>
> You will be waiting a very long time
> rolling dice for this effect to show
> up.
>
> Math.random() also requires about
> twice the processing and is subject to
> synchronization.

Comment: За ответ спасибо. Но есть еще мини-вопросик: чем плох метод Random.nextDouble()?

Comment: Дело не в самом nextDouble, а в том как он используется в Math.random().

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/summaries/summary-random.html) небольшая статья на эту тему.

Если вкратце, то **java.util.Random** более гибок с точки зрения получения равномерно распределенных случайных чисел, обеспечивает более легкую генерацию данных, отличных по типу от **double**, а также реализует распределение Гаусса.

Единственный минус - всегда нужно создавать новый объект, в отличии от простого вызова статического метода **java.lang.Math.random**.